# How to run 2 or more scripts from different directory in parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

As of now I a using *time parallel* to run scripts in parallel.
Example...
First, I'll go to the directory where the scripts are located.

```
cd $DIR
```

Then, execute scripts

```
time parallel ::: $script1 $script2 $script3
```

This works well.

But what if the scripts are in different directory?

Comment: Do they need to be run in different directories or just are placed in different directories?

Comment: they need to be run in different directories because of some dependent files.

Comment: @JaneS.: just give the full path of the script to your above example shown. It should work? no

Comment: @Inian But the 3 scripts are in different directories.

Comment: Have you tried? `time parallel ::: /blabla/blabla/blabla/abc/script1 /blabla/blabla/blabla/def/script2 /blabla/blabla/blabla/ghi/script3`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an ampersand (`&`) for background execution in bash, and `(command)` to run `command` in a subshell:

```
(cd $DIR1; $script1) &
(cd $DIR2; $script2) &
```

Comment: Nice answer, nohup can be combined to avoid the end of the scripts when the initial bash is killed!

Comment: Nice. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to `cd` into each directory, you can simply do:

```
time parallel --dry-run ::: dirA/dirB/script1 dirC/dirD/script2
```

**Sample Output**

```
dirA/dirB/script1
dirC/dirD/script2
```

---

If you do need to `cd` into each directory, you can do it like this:

```
time parallel --dry-run 'cd {//} && {/}' ::: dirA/dirB/script1 dirC/dirD/script2
```

**Sample Output**

```
cd dirA/dirB && script1
cd dirC/dirD && script2
```